# Getting Order Variables On Multiple Address Shipping Order Success Page in Magento

Tags: magento, variables, confirmation, google-trusted-stores

I've been searching and searching for how to display order information on the multiple address checkout order confirmation success page. I find lots of information on the one page checkoou but very little about the mutishipping checkout.

I need the information for Google Trusted Stores JavaScript, Adwords tracking mostly.

Here's all I've got to work so far:

```
1:<?php foreach ($_orderIds as $orderId=>$incrementId): ?>
2:<?php $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId()); ?>
3:<?php echo $_product->getName() ?><br />
4:<?php echo $orderId; ?><br />

5:<?php echo $incrementId; ?><br />
6:<?php echo $item->getBasePrice(); ?><br />

7:<?php echo $orderId->getGrandTotal(); ?><br />
8:<?php echo $orderId->getShippingAmount(); ?><br />
9:<?php echo $order->getGrandTotal(); ?><br />
0:<?php echo $order->getShippingAmount(); ?><br />
q:<?php echo $orderId->getTaxAmount(); ?><br />
w:<?php echo $order->getTaxAmount(); ?><br />
e:<?php echo (int)$item->getQtyOrdered(); ?><br />
r:<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getSku()); ?>
t:<?php echo htmlentities($customer->getEmail()); ?><br />


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Only numbers 3, 4 (strange as it displays the number 21 or some other number I'm not sure is), 5, and number 6. That's all.

I keep tinkering with it but it would be very nice to get these variables to display.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little instructional I used to get these variables up and running. Hopefully it will help you.

http://www.alphachannelgroup.com/custom-magento-order-confirmation/